# how to exploit read -p in bash script

Tags: linux, exploit, bash, bash-scripting

i wanna execute ls command inplace of the output being "your name is ls"
is there a way to do it ?

```
read -p "name??" name
    echo "your name is $name"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Bash (and other Posix shells) should be pretty immune to this, *especially* when the variable is contained within quotes.